# Как получить полную ссылку перехода на страницу?

Tags: javascript, аналитика

Нужно получить инфу откуда зашел на сайт клиент. 
Есть такое свойство: `document.referer`, но ото отображает лишь домен по сути, а хотелось бы всю ссылку.

К примеру. Мы перешли с гугл поиска. Как вы знаете в гугл поиске ссылка довольно таки длинная. Вот хотелось бы её получить.

Только JS. сервер не подходит. Подключать Гугл аналитику и прочее нет возможности.

Comment: Что значит только js? Только Ваш сервер обладает информацией о запросе к нему. Если он не добавит ничего в ответ, клиент ничего не узнает.

Comment: @vp_arth я действую со скрипта. Да и сервер тоже не узнает откуда пришел юзер, точнее полной ссылки там не будет, а только домен.

Comment: Если промежуточный сервер (Гугл, например) не предоставляет полной ссылки - разве у Вас есть выбор? Разве что, Вы можете подарить клиентам собственный браузер)

Comment: Вспомните как работает HTTP, и поймите, что только на совести клиента, что добавить в запрос, как и только на совести сервера, то что попадает в ответ. За то, что нам передают хоть какой-то Referer при редиректе - спасибо, ведь никто не обязан)

Comment: @vp_arth за это спасибо, да. Но есть люди которые как-то получают то что меня интересует. Но вот как у них узнать не получится.

Comment: @Tsyklop что за волшебные люди такие? Познакомьте нас с ними!